# How to make gradient in a line graph?

Tags: highcharts

I want to fill my line graph with a gradient, I use this configuration, but with the option `styledMode= true` it does not work. I am using Hightcharts 9.0

https://jsfiddle.net/yjqcz42n/92/

Answer (score 0):

**[As you can read in the docs:](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css)**

*When the `chart.styledMode` option is `true`, no presentational attributes (like fill, stroke, font styles etc.) are applied to the chart SVG. Instead, the design is applied purely by CSS.*

It means you need to style series using their CSS classes.

---

**Recommended solution:**

Due to the difficulty of styling gradients for the SVGs, there is a Highcharts guide doc, on how to configure **Gradients, shadows, and pattern fills in styled mode**

https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/gradients-shadows-and-patterns#gradients-shadows-and-pattern-fills-in-styled-mode

---

Alternative solution:

**HTML**

```
<svg width="0" height="0" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <style type="text/css">
        rect{fill:url(#MyGradient)}
      </style>
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="MyGradient">
          <stop offset="5%" stop-color="#F60" />
          <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#FF6" />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
</svg>
```

**CSS:**

```
.highcharts-series-0 {
  fill: url(#MyGradient);
  stroke: url(#MyGradient);
}
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/15rmcfyd/

Comment: What if I want to apply css styling and use a dynamic gradient at the same time? I do not really want to use gradient through svg and id as I have run into a problem: if the page more than one chart and one of them hide through invisible then the second chart disappears fill as it works html.

Comment: Hi, apologize for the oversight. Use the following guide doc https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/gradients-shadows-and-patterns#gradients-shadows-and-pattern-fills-in-styled-mode. I've already edited my answer with it as a recommended option.

Comment: This way of setting the id of a gradient element limits my use. I make a graph component and in it I create highcharts with the same id in js and css, but if there are 2 or more graphs on html page and one of them is hidden with invisible, then second graph loses fill-gradient, because that is how html works.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! For setting global options, you can use `setOptions()` which should prevent mentioned behavior.  Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/36ybkq7p/ API References: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.html#.setOptions

Comment: This works great! But I don't understand why the second graph didn't lose the gradient when hiding the first one via visibility hidden?

Comment: This is because the gradient is applied to all charts through Highcharts.setOptions(), so the second chart uses the global options for the gradient, and hiding/removing the first chart does not affect its options.

Comment: It still doesn't work with display:none https://jsfiddle.net/csedo043/3/

Comment: This is because the browser returns 0x0 px bounding box for `display: none` elements, and we use bounding boxes for some calculations. In that case it's better to use` visibility: hidden` instead or e.g. `position: absolute; top: -9999em; `

Comment: Maybe there is a possibility to influence the svg which is inside display:none, for example cascade override the display property or set the height?
Maybe I can make a patch in my cdn in Highcharts?