# How do I create a unique svg gradient for a line graph?

Tags: highcharts

I use highcharts to create a line graph, with the fill being a gradient. I encountered a problem that if there are two charts on a page with the same gradient id and one chart is hidden by display:none, then the second chart has no fill. How can I solve this problem?
Note: I use styleMode:true.

Comment: Hi, this question is related to your previous thread, so I provided the answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75067129/how-to-make-gradient-in-a-line-graph/75072131?noredirect=1#comment134922343_75072131